# Validation of Data inputed with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a divelog software for a computing project. I need a way of validating the data inputted by the user through `Tkinter`. I think the best way would be to validate the data after and then, if it is incorrect, have a error message window that will make the user re-enter the data.
Does any body know of a way to do this?
This is the a link to a pastebin of the code I am using for the data input: This is what I've tried so far:

```
E1_data = None #These four lines initialise the variables for data input using Tkinter
E2_data = None
E3_data = None
E4_data = None

def tkinput():
    root = Tk()

    label1 = Label(root, text="Dive Number: ")#label for the first data entry
    E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5)

    label2 = Label(root, text="Time In (24hr clock): ")#label for the second data entry
    E2 = Entry(root, bd = 5)

    label3 = Label(root, text="Time Out (24hr clock): ")#label for the third data entry
    E3 = Entry(root, bd = 5)

    label4 = Label(root, text="Max Depth: ")#label for the fourth data entry
    E4 = Entry(root, bd = 5)


    def get_data(): #Subroutine for getting the data and assigning it to a variable
       global E1_data
       E1_data = E1.get()
       global E2_data
       E2_data = E2.get()
       global E3_data
       E3_data = E3.get()
       global E4_data
       E4_data = E4.get()
       root.destroy()

    #these next lines render all of the required items onto the input window
    label1.pack() 
    E1.pack()
    label2.pack()
    E2.pack()
    label3.pack()
    E3.pack()
    label4.pack()
    E4.pack()

    submit = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = get_data) #creates the submit button to be displayed on the input window
    submit.pack(side = BOTTOM) #displays the button at the bottom of the input window
    root.mainloop() #runs the input module

tkinput()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keywords

> tkinter entry validation

in ddg or google direct you to

- [NMT Documentation on Tkinter Entry Widget Validation Commands](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html)
- [Effbot Documentation on How to manually create self Validating Entry Widgets](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm)

*What the documentation says:*

You can add a validation command / function / method to the entry widget itself just like a command callback.

This is **exactly** what you are looking for so i suppose you did not spend any time in research.

Yes the Effbot Link is from 1998 but the code still works. The *better* approach might nevertheless be validation commands implemented in Tkinter directly.

Comment: This seems like a "link only" answer to me. Could you summarize what those links say? Perhaps this OP didn't do much research, but it seems unfair to punish future researchers who happen upon this post :)

Comment: better like this? ;)

Comment: Ya that looks a little better. I followed the effbot link and it says: "Newer versions of Tkinter support validate and validatecommand options that can be used instead of the extra variable." That seems relevant - is that the same as adding a callback like you describe?

Comment: I ask because that effbot link is from 1998 and I got "in trouble" the other day for posting a 1998 effbot link with outdated info haha

Comment: added additional information on the topic